# Is an inertial force needed to be added to second Newton's law when transforming from cartesian to cylindrical coordinates?

Tags: electromagnetism, coordinate-systems, inertial-frames, rotational-kinematics

Let's consider I have a particle moving on the $x,y$ plane. On this particle acts the Lorentz force, however it does not necessary perform a rotation by the axes origin $(x,y)=(0,0)$. I would like to re-write the Lorentz force in the "global" cylindrical coordinate system where  the origin $(x,y)=(0,0)$ is the same as the $r=0$. Of course the particle motion will be described by $ R=r,\phi,z$ and $u=u_r, u_{\phi}, u_z$ in that coordinate system. Should I add an inertial force in this system, such as $m\frac{du}{dt} = F_L + F_{int}$, in my description?

Answer (score 0):

No, you should not, unless you "move" into a rotating or to another non inertial reference frame. The coordinates of a non inertial RF are expressed not only via the original ones, but also **explicitly** via time $t$ and in a "complicated" manner.

Comment: But the cylindrical coordinates are a rotating system? If yes, I suppose I have to add an inertial force

Comment: No, unless you explicitly specify the rotation law.

Comment: I do not know a priori if the particle rotates. I know that the particle "moves" in x-y plane under a Lorentz force and I would like to translate them in cylindrical $r,\phi$ polar plane

Comment: Rotation of a particle has nothing to do with non inertial RF from which you observe the particle motion. Solutions to the equations of motion are functions of time, but they do not make the RF rotate or whatever. In order to describe the particle motion in cylindrical coordinates, you just make the variable change with the known formulae. These formulae are "static".

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try and if I have some questions, I will return

Comment: In what case I would need to add an inertial force in the Newton's second law?

Comment: In no case. When you make a variable change, "new" terms will appear in the new equations autimatically. They may be "interpreted" as something, but you do not insert anything new by hand.

Answer (score 0):

First you write the equations of motion in Inertial system $\vec{R}=[x,y]^T$

$$m\,\vec{\ddot{R}}=F_L(\vec{R},\vec{\dot{R},t,\bar{q}})\tag 1$$

$F_L$ is the Lorentz force and $\bar{q}$ the electric charge

now you can transformed equation (1) to polar coordinates with:

$\vec{R}(x,y)\mapsto\vec{R}(r,\phi)$

$\vec{\dot{R}}=\frac{\partial \vec{R}}{\partial \vec{q}}\vec{\dot{q}}$

$\vec{\ddot{R}}=\frac{\partial \vec{R}}{\partial \vec{q}}\vec{\ddot{q}}+\vec{f_z}(\vec{q},\vec{\dot{q}})$

with: $\vec{q}=[r,\phi]^T\quad$,$\vec{\dot{q}}=[\dot{r},\dot{\phi}]^T$

$\Rightarrow$ equation (1)

$$m\,\left(\frac{\partial \vec{R}}{\partial \vec{q}}\vec{\ddot{q}}+\vec{f_z}(\vec{q},\vec{\dot{q}})\right)=F_L(\vec{q},\vec{\dot{q}},t,\bar{q})\tag 2$$

multiply equation (2) from the left with $J^T=\left(\frac{\partial \vec{R}}{\partial \vec{q}}\right)^T$ we obtain :

$$m\,J^T\,J\,\vec{\ddot{q}}=J^T\,F_l-m\,J^T\,\vec{f}_z\tag 3$$

Equation (3) are the equations of motion in polar coordiantes